# In Ansible Python module, how to differentiate between options passed as argument and options with default value?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

How can you differentiate between a non-required module parameter that's passed to an Ansible Python module with a null value, and a non-required module parameter that's not given in the invocation?

E.g. a module `person` with the following `module_args`:

```py
module_args = dict(
    ### Required parameters
    email = dict(type='str', default=None, required=True),
    state = dict(type='str', default=None, required=True, choices=['absent','present']),

    ### Optional parameters
    phoneNumber = dict(type='str', required=False, default=None),
    mobileNumber = dict(type='str', required=False, default=None),
)
```

If I don't pass the `phoneNumber` value in the invocation, I don't want to change it, but if I explicitly pass `phoneNumber: null` in the invocation, I want to clear it.

But in both cases, the invocation shows that the value passed is `null`.
Is there some way to determine whether a `module.params['param']` has value `None` in the module because it was explicitly given as `None` versus it has `None` because that's the default value when the parameter is omitted?

In other words:

```yaml
- name: Delete phone, leave mobile
  person:
    email: joe@foo.bar
    state: present
    phoneNumber: null
```

In this case, the `phoneNumber` should be deleted, and the `mobileNumber` should be left alone. But the invocation shows that both have `null` as value.

I currently have solved this by setting the default value not to `None` but to some random string, but that feels like a really ugly solution.

Comment: A simple solution would be to enter an empty string `phoneNumber: ''` if you want to clear it.